# Add custom event in C++ WinForm to inspect native collection

Tags: winforms, events, c++-cli, clr

I'm a learner of C++/CLI develop and recently i met a trouble about event handler.

The question is: I wanna add a custom Event in a winForm class which inherited System::Windows::Form, and the event must inspect a native collect (like std::deque). Whenever the size of the queue is changed, the event will do something.

I've tried to find the solution on MSDN already, but all i can find are custom managed ref class which is not i need.

Comment: Just have the code that alters the deque also fire the event.  Which might be a bit tricky if this lives buried in native C++ code.  It isn't clear at all what the hang-up might be, you'll have to document your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I assume that your native collection lies somewhere in native code (a library, namespace which uses only native c++...) otherwise I'd assume that you are working with this collection completely in .Net-Environment and then I'd like to ask you why not using one of the .net collections?

If my assumption is right and the collection lies in native code than I don't know how you could achieve this communication directly. I'm programming in C++/CLI for a while now and didn't see a way how to create an "event" in native code where .Net code reacts to.

But I would suggest to use the [observer-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or something similar which works almost as an event. To not mix native and .Net code all over your project I recommend to make a special observer class (your `observer`) which can be used by native code (your `subject`) without bringing in .Net code. It also knows the .Net Code (your `winForm`) and does the communication between both. This observer gets notfied by the subject(s) in your native code when the collection size changes and then calls the method in your `winForm`.

Additional Information for the interaction native c++ <-> c++/CLI (see comments below):

Because it isn't a simple thing to store a .Net reference in native code I recommended the extra observer class to encapsulate the interaction.
In your case this means not to try to implement the `winform` directly as a observer class. With the additional native observer class between your subject class and the `winForm` you can easily register the observer and you have the problem storing a managed reference only in this class. You have 2 options:

1. Implement the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your `winForm` to get a reference to your living instance of the Form. References can be stored temporarily as asual with `Type^`. You could use this to get the reference in the notify-method.
2. Implement the native observer class and store the reference from the beginning by using [gcroot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this case you maybe have to do some casts.

In both cases you then call at the notify method a public method of the `winForm` which does with the collection whatever has to be done. Also the references to the .Net Framework have to be setup for the project including this observer class (should already be done when all classes lie in the same project as the `winForm`).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Actually, my dev environment is .net (C++/CLR), but i must reuse an existed communication model which has own protocol to communicate between client/server. The collection i used is based on std::deque but much extended. Now there's such a collection in my winForm (a member of form class), and whenever it received something, the data will be pushed into the queue and for further implementation. However, i don't know how to inspect the queue.size()...

Comment: Do you have access to the complete code of this collection? If so, use the observer-pattern as mentioned (the collection will be the subject where observers can be (un)registered and notified (at best from every method were the data are added into the collection)).
Native classes can be accessed as usual, you're just not allowed to stores instances of native classes in .Net code

Comment: yes i have. i've read the observer pattern but still have some question that: in clr, this pointer cannot be passed to native code, so how to register observer?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how the native <-> clr interaction could be achieved. Explaining how you can register the observer and then access your `winForm`